# Biped Kinematics (HTM)

Tags: inverse-kinematics, jacobian, humanoid

Some notations:

1. IRF: inertia reference frame or world frame
2. CoM: center of mass
3. DoF: degree of freedom [x y z roll pitch yaw]

I'm trying to implement the **simplest kind of biped walking** using  3D LIPM and Preview Control by Kajita.

It seems that the ZMP_ref is designed in the IRF.
So, the [x y] trajectory command for the CoM is also in IRF, while keeping other 4DoF [Zc 0 0 yaw].

And we kind of "integrate" the leg motion and CoM motion to get CoM position and use the inverse Jacobian(in IRF) to calculate the joint command.

But this seems to be weird if I want to implement the joy-stick control.It seems like "integrating" the CoM command [x y Zc 0 0 yaw] is needed.

I'm thinking about using support sole as reference frame to calculate Jacobian, it's seems easier to give yaw rotating command to control the robot.

Because most of the papers about turning did not show the details like this.

Have any seniors encountered such problems?
Any suggestions would be helpful !